# When will new gTLD applications be available?

Tags: domains, domain-registrar, top-level-domains, icann, tld-restrictions

The ICANN "New gTLD Program" was initiated in 2012:

> https://icannwiki.org/New_gTLD_Program

Applicants applied for a variety of new TLDs, many of which are now available for public registration in the years since 2012, such as `.coffee`, `.space`, `.pizza`, and `.app`.

Is there a planned successor to this program?

Has there been an announced application process for post-2012 new gTLDs?

Will TLD applications become available on an ongoing basis? Or is another time-limited application batch planned to be run in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a planned successor to this program?

Yes, currently being worked on.

> Has there been an announced application process for post-2012 new gTLDs?

No, as the various works needed are not finished.

> Will TLD applications become available on an ongoing basis?

That was the plan initially (the 2012 round being considered just as a first test), but I think I have read this won't be the case anymore anyway.

> Or is another time-limited application batch planned to be run in the future?

Difficult to know yet.

Everyone will speculate on the above items, so don't believe anything until it is published on ICANN website.
Their new gTLDs website is supposed to be https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/ but don't expect it to be choke ful of up to date information...

If you have time and soothing drugs freely available, you can have a look at recent meetings/public comments on the subject, such as:

- https://www.icann.org/public-comments/gnso-gtld-subsequent-procedures-final-outputs-2021-04-22-en
- https://www.icann.org/public-comments/gnso-rpm-pdp-phase-1-final-recommendations-2021-04-07-en
- https://www.icann.org/public-comments/ncap-study-1-2020-02-13-en
- https://www.icann.org/public-comments/rpm-initial-report-2020-03-18-en
- https://www.icann.org/public-comments/gnso-new-gtld-subsequent-draft-final-report-2020-08-20-en
- etc. (nearly an infinite list)